# Multiple Errors When Writing C++ in Sublime Text 3

Tags: c++, gcc, sublimetext3

Let me preface this by saying I have searched (for a few days now) for answers to these questions and can't find anything that solves the problem. In fact, I think I've only made it worse.

Also, when it comes to programming, I am a complete beginner and am teaching myself C++ (I know, I know, you're not supposed to start with C++ as your first programming language).

I know in the StackOverflow guidelines it says to describe your problem first before posting any code but part of my problem is that I don't even understand what the problem is...

For reference, I'm running Windows 7 64-bit and writing my code in Sublime Text 3 (build 3059) and, well, I'm not entirely sure what I'm compiling it with, I mean I have gcc installed(?) but I'm thinking that's part of the problem- I installed something called Cygnus as well as MinGW and Visual Studio Express 2012 but I'm not sure if these are actually compilers/I simply don't know what they do. Also, I've modified my Environment Path variable several times which was probably a bad idea.

Anyway, here is the code for the first of the two problems:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  cout << "Hello World! ";
 return 0;
}
```

When I "build" the code, it works fine, however when I attempt to run it, this is the error that I get:

```
bash.exe: warning: could not find /tmp, please create!
[sig] C:\cygnus\cygwin-b20\H-i586-cygwin32\bin\bash.exe 1020 (0) call_handler: couldn't get context of main thread, error 998
```

I've searched for how to add/create bash but truthfully did not understand the answers that I found.

Here is my second problem. I'm learning C++ from Stroustrup's "The C++ Programming Language, 4th Edition" which, for several chapters, asks the reader to include a header ("std_lib_facilities.h") which I have saved and placed in the folder along with my practice files. This is some code I've written myself (which is probably all wrong) but even copying code from the book and running it generates this error. (I've tried just using #include  and using namespace std; however things still don't work.)

```
//convert from miles to kilometers. 1.609km in 1 mile
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
int main()
{
    cout >> "Please enter a length in miles: " >> endl;
    float miles = 0;
    cin << miles;
    float kilometers = 1.609;
    float result = miles / kilometers;
    cout >> miles >> " miles is equal to " >> kilometers >> endl;


    return 0;
}
```

The error it generates when I attempt to build it is extremely long so I'll post a snippet of it:

```
In file included from c:\users\brekki\gcc\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-   mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../include/c++/4.7.0/ext/hash_map:61:0,
             from C:\Users\brekki\Desktop\CPP\MINE\std_lib_facilities.h:21,
             from C:\Users\brekki\Desktop\CPP\MINE\mtokm.cpp:2:
c:\users\brekki\gcc\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64- mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../include/c++/4.7.0/backward/backward_warning.h:33:2: warning:  #warning This file includes at least one deprecated or antiquated header which may be  removed without further notice at a future date. Please use a non-deprecated interface with  equivalent functionality instead. For a listing of replacement headers and interfaces,  consult the file backward_warning.h. To disable this warning use -Wno-deprecated. [-Wcpp]
C:\Users\brekki\Desktop\CPP\MINE\mtokm.cpp: In function 'int main()':
C:\Users\brekki\Desktop\CPP\MINE\mtokm.cpp:5:10: error: no match for 'operator>>' in  'std::cout >> "Please enter a length in miles: "'
C:\Users\brekki\Desktop\CPP\MINE\mtokm.cpp:5:10: note: candidates are:
In file included from c:\users\brekki\gcc\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-  mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../include/c++/4.7.0/string:55:0,
             from c:\users\brekki\gcc\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64- mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../include/c++/4.7.0/bits/locale_classes.h:42,
             from c:\users\brekki\gcc\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../include/c++/4.7.0/bits/ios_base.h:43,
             from c:\users\brekki\gcc\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64- mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../include/c++/4.7.0/ios:43,
             from c:\users\brekki\gcc\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64- mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../include/c++/4.7.0/ostream:40,
             from c:\users\brekki\gcc\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64- mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../include/c++/4.7.0/iostream:40,
             from C:\Users\brekki\Desktop\CPP\MINE\std_lib_facilities.h:4,
             from C:\Users\brekki\Desktop\CPP\MINE\mtokm.cpp:2:
```

When I attempt to run the program, I get a similar error except it is preceded by the "bash.exe: warning:"

- My ideas as for what the problem(s) could be are:
- I've somehow screwed up my Path variables
- My GCC files are outdated
- Trying to use too many compilers
- Bad Sublime Text 3 C++ build
- Stroustrup's header causing obvious issues

Sorry for the long, possibly stupid question. Any insight at all would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I do have Visual Studio Express 2012 installed as well.

Comment: `std::cout` uses `<<`, not `>>`. `std::cin` uses `>>`, not `<<`.

Comment: For the deprecated header warning, you can *try* [this modified `std_lib_facilities.h`](http://pastebin.com/dE2viXZG). I won't guarantee that it will work, so make a backup of the other one first. Note that you will need to compile with `-std=c++11`. I don't know what other substitute for an unordered map there is. I haven't read the book, but I don't think that header is used for very long anyway. It's mostly just some hacks to simplify learning and catch mistakes for beginners.

Comment: The other option as long as you keep your GCC version the same (a future one could get rid of that header) is to to compile with `-Wno-deprecated` and just ignore the warning about the deprecated header. In the future, if you need a hash map in your own code, there's one in `<unordered_map>`. The book was simply written three years before that header officially existed, so it had to work around that.

Comment: Kudos for 1) admitting that you don't know what you don't know, 2) giving a lot of good information in your question and 3) starting with `HelloWorld`. I wish I could be of help, but this looks to me more like a Windows problem than anything else.

Answer (score 2):

First at all, MinGW and Cygnus are just installer for the GCC compiler. As Preet Kukreti allready commented, you should try an IDE like Visual Studio Express or otherwise if you didn't want the Microsoft thing you should try CodeBlocks which is also free.

I wouldn't recommend to learn C++ on Windows without a IDE. When you want to programm C++ with a text editor and the command line, you should probably go with linux.

Comment: Normally I wouldnt upvote a response like this, but the sad truth is that you are fighting an uphill battle working with GCC or clang on Windows without a proper IDE. Windows is simply a poorly suited env for such toolchains. MSVC and VS are the best option for a beginner on Windows. Later on, when you develop skill and taste, your opinion might change, but for now, reduce the number of battles you are fighting.

Comment: I've been doing fine with GCC and Clang using Sublime Text 3. That is with MinGW rather than Cygwin, though.

Comment: @PreetKukreti You're right- I thought that I'd be okay with something like Sublime Text (and I wanted to stick with it because I liked the dark background) but I'm coming to the conclusion that a regular IDE is the way to go for now (and I've figured out how to make the background dark as well!).

Comment: @brekki, If you want something similar in VS, import this: https://studiostyl.es/schemes/monokai. Of course the options in there have a Fonts and Colors section, too, for finer-grained tuning. Still, it resembles Sublime's colours pretty well.

Comment: @brekki Just for the record: I work on windows with Sublime Text and I do build from Sublime Text with msbuild (my fellow colleague are working with Visual Studio). It is feasible but not straightforward. And you should first concentrate on the language itself.

Comment: As far as using the command line is concerned, I don't see how learning C++ with VC on Windows is different than doing so with GCC on Linux. Why is it harder to type `cl /W4 /Za /EHsc test.cpp` than to type `g++ -Wall -std=c++03 -o test test.cpp`?